# Passing complex parameters with MVC4 RESTful web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a complex object to a MVC4 web api controller:

```
public class DnsController : ApiController
{

        public IEnumerable<DnsARecord> GetDnsARecords(DnsServer dnsServer, string domainName)
        {...
```

and I'm expecting to call this from an HttpClient:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // Send a request asynchronously continue when complete
        httpClient.GetAsync(dnsApiUrl).ContinueWith(...
```

The above code I've borrowed from the ["Introduction to HttpClient"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee) sample - the code is listed on the page.

I was wondering how I should pass the two parameters. I am assuming that some pre-processing is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as many parameters as you want in the HTTP-GET query string. Just have to add the route template to the server.

```
var server = new HttpSelfHostServer();
server.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DnsQuery", "api/{controller}/dnsserver={DnsServer}&domain={domainName}");
```

The values passed in for dnsserver and domain will now map to your GET method parameters.

---

Edit:
Alternatively, you can also pass complex objects in the body of an HTTP POST. The three native formats you can choose from are JSON, XML, or UrlEncoded Query String. MVC4 knows how to map these data formats to simple variables such as strings (just make sure the xml element names have the same name as the parameter you want them to map to. Also the client sending the request must ensure the content-type must is set to the proper value (Application/JSON, Text/XML, application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

```
<DnsInfo>
    <DnsServer>0.0.0.0</DnsServer>
    <Domain>YourDomain.com</Domain>
</DnsInfo>
```

---

You can also create a Complex type and it will be deserilized into it

```
void Post(DnsInfo info) : ApiController
{
}

public class DnsInfo
{
    public string DnsServer { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

The advantages to this method is that it will help if you have too many parameters, it will be better to organize them into classes instead. In addition if you are passing any sensitive information you do not want to use query strings in the url as these can be cached by browsers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep one input parameter for you API method and supply all additional params using URL Parameters.

And call your method as follows:

```
  http:/localhost/MyApp/Dns/GetDnsARecords/ns1.x.com?domainName=mywebsite.com
```

In your method you just catch the value by doing

```
   var domainName = HttpContext.Current.Request["domainName"];
```

Answer (score -1):

I think for get posts, you request data  has to go into the url. Maybe you can use the URL Form Formatter? 
How does the API look like?

Comment: For the time being I've simplified my API and passed the relevant information in the url path. It works, but I have to make more database calls.  I was still hoping that there may be another mechanism that allowed the passing of (say) JSON data without being visible on the query string, perhaps though the use of header data.  I don't know enough about the HTTP protocol to know whether this is (a) possible or (b) desirable.

Comment: There are some rules on when to use a GET or a POST request. If you wanna pass lots of data in a JSON, then a POST request might be the best thing to do. A simplified rule is to use GET to retrieve things (but not change  anything) and POST if you have to update or create something on the server. But there are tons of discussions about this on the net. Just google post vs. get vs. put

Comment: It's definitely a GET that I want but I was hoping to decorate the page with related information drawn from the calling page.